# How to init pscustomobjects array in pscustomobject

Tags: json, powershell, hashtable, pscustomobject

I try to make an object like this:

```
$bodyObject = [pscustomobject]@{
    'fields' = [pscustomobject]@{
        'fixVersions' = @([pscustomobject]@{
            'id' = $releaseId
        })
    }
};
$bodyJson = $bodyObject | ConvertTo-Json;
Write-Output $bodyJson;
```

I got the following output:

```
{
    "fields": {
        "fixVersions": [
            "@{id=16919}"
        ]
    }
}
```

How can I achieve valid JSON structure like this?

```
{
    "fields": {
        "fixVersions": [
            {"id": "16919"}
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: `ConvertTo-Json` -> `ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3` (you might want to set it to a higher number if you have deeply nested objects)

Comment: That's true! Thank you, I just wrote similar answer by myself just after reading MSDN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I just composed a question, the idea came to me.
The problem was not in the way of creating my complex object, but in json serilizator.
According to docs, default -Depth parameter value is 2. So, I changed the code like this

```
$bodyObject = [pscustomobject]@{
    'fields' = [pscustomobject]@{
        'fixVersions' = @([pscustomobject]@{
            'id' = $releaseId
        })
    }
};
$bodyJson = $bodyObject | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3; # HERE
Write-Output $bodyJson;
```

and got a correct JSON